# SQLite query to get corresponding data

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have some database tables that holds rooms and another table that holds exits of that rooms:

rooms Table:

```
+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| uid (integer) | name (varchar) | area (varchar) |
+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

exits Table:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
| direction  | fromuid | touid |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

there is 6 possible direction for each room: north, south, west, east, up, down

I want to get all `uid`s from current `uid` to all directions with 3 depth.

What I mean is: for example for north room's north room and that one's north room and that one's north room also.

```
         |n3|                    |u3|
         |n2|                    |u2|
         |n1|                    |u1|
|w3|w2|w1|  |e1|e2|e3|    and
         |s1|                    |d1|
         |s2|                    |d2|
         |s3|                    |d3|
```

Like this I want to get all rooms `uid`s with keys like n1, n2, n3 etc.

Is that possible with one query?

Also note that some directions are not have 3 rooms. For example east direction can have only 1 room or other directions cant have any room at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you want:

```
select  rooms.uid           as origin,
        exits1.direction    as direction1,
        exits1.touid        as room1,
        exits2.direction    as direction2,
        exits2.touid        as room2,
        exits3.direction    as direction3,
        exits3.touid        as room3
    from rooms
    left outer join exits exits1
        on rooms.uid = exits1.fromuid
    left outer join exits exits2
        on exits1.touid = exits2.fromuid
    left outer join exits exits3
        on exits2.touid = exits3.fromuid
```

This is not filtering on starting direction so if the 2nd north room connects to an up room, you will get that. Or if a room has more than one connection. To filter on the starting direction, use this one:

```
select  rooms.uid           as origin,
        exits1.direction    as direction1,
        exits1.touid        as room1,
        exits2.direction    as direction2,
        exits2.touid        as room2,
        exits3.direction    as direction3,
        exits3.touid        as room3
    from rooms
    left outer join exits exits1
        on rooms.uid = exits1.fromuid
    left outer join exits exits2
        on exits1.touid = exits2.fromuid
        and exits1.direction = exits2.direction
    left outer join exits exits3
        on exits2.touid = exits3.fromuid
        and exits2.direction = exits3.direction
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I want